# Sapper: is it safe to render sensitive data, based on user rights?

Tags: svelte, sapper

I want to render 500 error's traceback came from server only for admin, so:

1. In `server.js`, session is populated with user retrieved from http_only cookie, just something like `{'username': 'admin'}`

```
polka()
    .use(
        sapper.middleware({
            session: (req, res) => {
                return { 'user': parseCookie('user') }
            }
        })
    )
    .listen(PORT);
```

2. In some `index.js` there is a global variable to store possible traceback of 500 error came from server:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const error = writable();
```

3. In `index.html` article is preloaded, and in case of 500 error, traceback is rendered below if current user is admin:

```
<script context="module">

    import { error } from 'index.js';

    export async function preload(page, session) {
        return { article : await this.fetch('/api/article/').then(response => {
            if (response.status == 500 && session.user.username === 'admin') {
                error.set(response);
            }
            return response.json();
        })}
    }
</script>

<script>
    export let article
</script>

<h1>{ article.title }</h1>
<div>{ article.text }</div>

<!-- 500 ERROR TRACEBACK --->
{#if $error}
    {@html $error}
{/if}
```

---

So, if `$error` is set via `preload` function, will it be safe and rendered only server-side?
If not, how can it be improved?
Maybe `if (process.browser)` could help somehow?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Check the below answer by Rich Harris

### Original

If you have used one of the templates with either webpack or rollup you will see that `process.browser` is replaced with `true` meaning that unreachable code will be tree shaked.

So short answer would be yes, you should be fine to use it as long as you surround that code with `process.browser` in appropriate place

But with that being said you are better off relying on server logs when it comes to 500 error code. Returning just error code to all of the users and nothing more, and pushing stack traces to log system instead for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using stores like this.

Imagine that `response.json()` takes a few milliseconds to resolve, and in that time a new request happens that *also* errors. The first user is a regular user, the second user is an admin. Since the `error` store is common to all users who connect to that server, the first user would see the error meant for the admin user in that scenario.

Instead, just expose `error` as a prop:

```html
<script context="module">
    export async function preload(page, session) {
        const response = await this.fetch('/api/article/');

        return {
            article: await response.json(),
            error: response.status === 500 && session.user.username === 'admin'
                ? response
                : null
        };
    }
</script>

<script>
    export let article;
    export let error;
</script>

<h1>{ article.title }</h1>
<div>{ article.text }</div>

<!-- 500 ERROR TRACEBACK --->
{#if error}
    {@html error}
{/if}
```

(To be more rigorous still, it's better to avoid using the `session` object in this way, since someone sufficiently dedicated could find a way to access that object and mutate it — the server should be responsible for determining what information to show the user, not the client. Though in this case it doesn't really matter since you're just displaying information that is easily accessible via the network tab.)

Comment: Oh, big thx, did not know that stores are unique for whole process among all users. Sure such thing must be controlled by server, just wanted to understand sapper lifecycle deeper. Can you clarify please, "sufficiently dedicated" - is a man who can use some frontend vulnerability like csrf/xss or it can be accessed somehow event without any vulnerabilities?

Comment: I basically mean someone exploiting a vulnerability of some sort (which could be as simple as you or a coworker putting `window.session = stores().session` in a component somewhere to help you debug, then forgetting to take it out